# Mutiple AJAX requests out of order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, rest

I have a script here which does mutliple AJAX requests to get multiple stock quotes from a REST service. However the results which I get are out of order.

Here is my console log sequence TSLA -> TSLA -> AAPL -> TSLA -> AAPL -> ATT

### Is there something out of order in my code? Why am i getting the output multiple times?

```
    var jsonResultArray = new Array();
    var StockQuotes = {};
    /**
    * Define the QuoteService.
    * First argument is symbol (string) for the quote. Examples: AAPL, MSFT, JNJ, GOOG.
    * Second argument is fCallback, a callback function executed onSuccess of API.
    */
    StockQuotes.QuoteService = function(sSymbol, fCallback) {
        console.log("Entering quote serivce");
        this.symbol = sSymbol;
        this.fCallback = fCallback;
        this.DATA_SRC = "http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp";
        for(index in sSymbol){
            this.makeRequest(sSymbol[index]);
            console.log(sSymbol[index])
        }
    };
    /**
    * Ajax success callback. fCallback is the 2nd argument in the QuoteService constructor.
    */
    StockQuotes.QuoteService.prototype.handleSuccess = function successHandler(jsonResult) {
        console.log("Entering handle success");
        jsonResultArray.push(jsonResult)
        this.fCallback(jsonResultArray);
        if(this.xhr) {this.xhr.abort();}
    };
    /**
    * Ajax error callback
    */
    StockQuotes.QuoteService.prototype.handleError = function errorHandler(jsonResult) {
        console.log("Entering handle error");
        console.error(jsonResult.Message);
    };
    /**
    * Starts a new ajax request to the Quote API
    */
    StockQuotes.QuoteService.prototype.makeRequest = function requestHandler(currentSymbol) {
        console.log("Entering make request");
        //Abort any open requests
    //    while (this.xhr) {  }
        //Start a new request
        this.xhr = $.ajax({
            data: { symbol: currentSymbol},
            url: this.DATA_SRC,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            async: "false",
            success: this.handleSuccess,
            error: this.handleError,
            context: this
        });
    };

    new StockQuotes.QuoteService(["T","AAPL","TSLA"], function finalOutput(jsonResultArray) {
        console.log("Entering final output");
        for(i in jsonResultArray){
            console.log(i);

            //If all goes well, your quote will be here.
            console.log(jsonResultArray[i]);

        }

    });
```

Comment: requests are asynchronous, so if one takes 700ms, next only 350ms...second will return before first

Comment: By the way, your naming of `sSymbol` is wrong, it's not a string, it's an array of strings, maybe `asSymbols`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `handleSuccess` -- it augments `jsonResultArray` for every result, and invokes the callback each time:

```
jsonResultArray.push(jsonResult)
this.fCallback(jsonResultArray);
```

I suppose you could either:

1. Pass only the current result instead, `this.fCallback(jsonResult)` (this would invoke the callback multiple times, as each result arrives).
2. OR run the callback only when all results have come back.  At first glance, it seems you can simply use a member variable `this.resultCount`, increment it on each error/success handler, and compare it to the number of requests.  But this becomes a bit more complex if you ever want to run multiple `QuoteService` calls simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using jQuery, there's an easy way to make your callback only be called when all the requests are finished. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

```
// I removed error handling, you'll have to do that
StockQuotes.QuoteService = function(sSymbol, fCallback) {
    var reqs = [];
    for (var i=0; i < sSymbol.length; i++) {
        reqs.push($.ajax({
            data: { symbol: sSymbol[i]},
            url: "http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            async: "false"
       }));
    }

    $.when.apply($, reqs).done(function(){
        fCallback.apply(arguments);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to determine what order your requests will be responded to. The requests can follow different paths across the internet, and the server may respond to them in a different order. What you can do is wait until all requests have been responded to and then work with them in the correct order.